# In SSH connection from one Unix machine to another : To know from which user the SSH was done

Tags: unix, ssh, client, parent

I might be asking a dumb question and I am apologizing for it.

Suppose I have two unix machine, for eg: machine1 and machine2.

1. First, I have logged into machine1 using userid1.
2. I am connecting to the machine2 using below SSH command and it is successful.
    **"ssh userid2@machine2"**
3. In the machine2, I want to know the from which userid of machine1 the SSH was performed 
   i.e **I want to know the userid1 value or name.**
4. Based on which userid1 it was logged in to the machine2 I have to run particular commands.

If parent user = userid1 then 
       source ./temp_file
endif

So, is there a way to implement this?
Thanking you in advance.